# bundling multiple typescript definition files with your npm package

Tags: javascript, typescript

The documentation for Typescript indicates that [publishing the typings for a Javascript package as part of the Javascript package itself](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/declaration-files/publishing.html) should be preferred.
The documentation indicates that a single file name is placed in the `packages.json` file.

```
"main": "./lib/main.js",
"types": "./lib/main.d.ts"
```

This is fine but I would prefer to have a single file corresponding to each of the Javascript files for which the typings are being written.
Can declaration files import other declarations files?
If so how?

Comment: It appears that placing `/// <reference path="xyz.d.ts" />` lines in the `main.d.ts` might work. Is that the right way to do it?

Comment: There is nothing preventing you from doing `import x from './x'` in your `*.d.ts` file.

You can take a look at https://github.com/types/npm-chai/tree/master/lib for examples